# Page Speed in appending external js and css files

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-rendering, external-links

i simply would like to know from who has well documented about, if i have 10 js/css external files to append at my site  does is better to compress them into only 1 file or is good to have 10,20  external source links anyway in a page speed point of view?

i also ask this, cause using both firebug google page speed and yahoo Yslow page speed tools, they conflict in this, google says to separate files, yahoo says compress all in one :| .. normally i would trust in bigG but who knows :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, compressing files is (nearly) always a good idea. Both using specific JS and/or CSS compressors, and using GZIP compression at the HTTP-level.

Deciding whether to combine files or not is not so easy; you need to juggle different goals:

1. Minimize the total number of bytes loaded; this includes making sure files can be retrieved from cache
2. Make sure the files loaded arrive in as few requests as possible.

Combining files optimizes for #2, but can be at the cost of #1. If different pages use different CSS / JS, then every page might get a different combined file (permutation of component files), making caching impossible.

A quick-and-dirty solution is to include all generic JavaScript and all CSS used on all the pages in two single compressed files (one JS, one CSS). If your visitors stay on your site for a longer time they will have the best experience, since all CSS/JS needs to be loaded only once, and that one time is as quick as possible.

Answer (score 3):

One of the key performance enhancements you can make is to reduce the number of HTTP requests. Each external resource means one extra request, so grouping them together will have a positive impact on page performance.

If you want to learn more about front-end performance, check out **[Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/)**' books. You can find a simplified overview of the topics in the books on the [Yahoo! Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) (he was at Yahoo! when he wrote the first book).

Comment: this i thought too!! hoping all users can confirm this .. will wait for also other answers ;)

Comment: [Minimize HTTP Requests](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http) also, there are a lot of other good tips on that page

Comment: The key is to benchmark it. Minimizing http request is always a good idea. But there are many other things to do first -- like using a CDN, caching, etc...

Comment: i can edit my question, but the case i'm referring to is 'multiple or only 1 external source file in a single medium-slow domain server'  then if you are able to use more then 1 domain server i catched is better to serve static files from other domains

Comment: if your server has a slow response time, then having two or three request at a time will be faster. If your server has low request overhead -- then it may not. Having fewer request is usually better because your browser will only send a few request at a time to a domain. The link above is a way to fool your browser into downloading more in parallel by using sub domains.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine your scripts into one script on one host and this host is slow -- your page will be slow. If you have your script broken up into a few scripts hosted on a CDN with different sub domains for the scripts, your browser will download more of them in [parallel](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/parallel/). Read that site on boosting download times. It has the conclusion "boosting parallel downloads can realize up to a 40% improvement in web page latency. You can use two or three hostnames to serve objects from the same server to fool browsers into multithreading more objects."

Comment: nice answer thanks, really don't know who sign as the answer, you says 1 thing and @Alex Ciminian Alex says 1 more thing %)

Comment: developers spend weeks on optimizing static files with minifying, compressing, and combining files. While these buy some speed improvements -- you wont even come close to what you gain by moving to a proper CDN with caching.

Comment: Ah, but the problem is, that Javascript cannot download in parallel (some newer browsers perhaps, but not if you wish to optimize for IE). As soon as you start downloading a script, everything else stops rendering, until the script is done downloading and executing.

Therefore, in most cases, it would be much better to merge and minimize your scripts.

In some cases, it makes sense to keep your scripts separated. For instance, if you have a heavy script, that is only being used in some hidden away place on your site. No need to download that, if it's not being used.

Comment: See http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/07/22/non-blocking-scripts/ and http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/.  still faster to do in parallel -- you have many options for how to get over the block.  ( but +1 on your comment because its something you need to consider!)

Comment: As Nix says the JavaScript will block the UI thread in a lot of browsers

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the Google Page Speed, YSlow and Firebug addons installed, then use them. They will help you make your website faster.

Comment: check my question .. i just use them :)

Comment: It's better to combine your 10 files into 1 file so there are less requests, but you might not want to do that.